# c++: Two issues with variadic function: int conversion error and passing arguments

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I'm writing a logging class and for that to be useful I need a variadic function that is similar to printf:

```
void Logger::log(std::string message, int level, const char* fmt...) {
  int bufferSize = 1000;
  char buffer[bufferSize];
  int cx = snprintf(buffer, bufferSize, message.c_str(), fmt);

  if (cx >= 0 && cx < bufferSize) {
    Logger::log(buffer, level);
  } else {
    Logger::error("Logger Error with variadic arguments");
  }
}
```

The function has two issues:

First, obviously I cannot simply pass `fmt` to `snprintf()`, but I'm at a loss how I can achieve this?

Second, when my program calls Logger:log() with the first variadic parameter being an integer it throws an error `invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]` at compile time:

This is the call in question, pos.x and pos.y are both int:

`Logger::log("  %d/%d", Logger::LVL_DEBUG, dirty->pos.x, dirty->pos.y);`

In contrast, this works:
`Logger::log("  %s", Logger::LVL_DEBUG, "hello World");`

Comment: Whats the `const char* fmt` doing in there? Your format is your first string.

Comment: This is not a variadic function, in C++ terms. Your first step is to figure out exactly what you want to do: implement either the old C-style varargs, or modern C++ template-based approach.

Comment: Use **variadic template** instead of **variadic functions**.

Comment: c-style variadic functions are the old, hacky, and difficult way. Read about variadic templates. There is an example here that is rather close to what you want to do https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Comment: If you really want to stick to variadic arguments then you will have to use `vsnprintf` instead of `snprintf`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone above, I have solved it by shuffling the parameters around and using vsprintf()

```
void Logger::log(int level, const char* fmt...) {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, fmt);

  int bufferSize = 1000;
  char buffer[bufferSize];
  int cx = vsprintf(buffer, fmt, args);

  va_end(args);

  if (cx >= 0 && cx < bufferSize) {
    Logger::log(buffer, level);
  } else {
    Logger::error("Logger error while using dynamic parameters");
  }
}
```